# Download files from a branch git

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal

I want to download all files from a branch in a repository. Let's say I have the branches **dev** and **master** in my **REP** repository. I want to download all the files from the branch **master**.

If I do `git clone` I get all the branches and the `.git` folder. What I want to do is just download the files inside a branch without any extra files. Is this possible?

Comment: No it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is to limit bandwidth, then you can do

```
git clone --depth 1 http://git_url
```

it will only clone the last commit.

If you absolutely want no other file, you may do

```
git clone --depth 1 http://git_url
rm -rf git_repo/.git
```